# Hibernate Problem ( javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException)

Tags: hibernate, jpa, persistence

Here is my problem description.

I have 2 Objects "A" and "B"."A" has a OneToOne(cascadeType= cascadeType.All)  relationship with another object "C".Even "B" has OneToOne(cascadeType = cascadeType.All) relationship with "C".

Now i need to persist the object "A".And after i persist the object "A" ,i need to persist the object "B".I can successfully persist the object "A" ,but when i persist "B" i get the exception

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException
```

The Reason for that is already the object "C" is persisted when "A" is persisted.And when "B" is being persisted it also tries to persist "C" again.Thats why the persistenceException.

I tried to merge the object C before i persist object "B".Even then i get the same exception.

Please provide me with a work around.

Also let me know if any one needs any further info.

Here is the Full Stack Trace

```
   Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.project.shared.entity.User
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1235)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1168)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1174)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:674)
        at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.persist(EntityManagerWrapper.java:258)
        at com.project.server.bean.ExpertFacade.create(ExpertFacade.java:64)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1052)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1124)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:5243)
        at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:615)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:797)
        at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:567)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doAround(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:157)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:139)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor64.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:858)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:797)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:367)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:5215)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:5203)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:190)
        ... 69 more
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide the full stacktrace, please?

Comment: Yes i edited my question and pasted the stack trace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Detached entity is an entity that has an identifier, but is not present in the current session. When you try to save it, hibernate complains. You have to put it back in the session. This is done via `entityManager.merge(..)`.

Comment: I merged the object "C" before persisting the Object "B". what i did is        getEntityManager().merge(Object"B".get"C");and then getEntityManager().persist(Object"B");Still i encounter the same exception

Comment: merge B as well - it appears it is the detached object (although cascade=all includes 'merge', right now I can't focus on your exact scenario)

Answer (score 2):

I got the same exception below:

```
Exception in thread "SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-2" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.tea.domain.User
```

When I modified the user object as below, I didn't get the exception:

```
@Override
    public void samplePull(Application application, User user) {

        user = userDao.findUser(user.getId());
        more code below.....

      }
```